# Compute average of past k-values in a data stream with limited memory

Tags: algorithm, mean, data-stream

I am not looking for particular code, more of general theory of what could be done for the problem.

We have a stream of incoming data (data entries are quite large, thus it is infeasible to store more than a few M of them in memory). The goal is to find the average of the last K entries we have seen in the stream, with K >> M. We have some statistical information about the data (which we can realistically compute online as data comes) such as mean and variance. Incoming data is a result of several unknown stochastic processes.

How could we approximate the last K elements-mean in such a setting?

Of course if M were close enough to K or greater than K, the problem can be trivially solved, by simply storing past M values and approximating the mean based on them. But if you assume a great difference between the two values (M = 4, K = 400), this approximation quickly degrades in quality. Compressing the data points to reduce the memory they take is not a sufficient enough increase (M' <= 3M, where M' is the the number of compressed entries we can store). A linear/quadratic/cubic approximation of the past K entries (based on just the last value we have seen), results in error approximately as bad as just using the past M entries.

Comment: Instead of the past M entries, divide the last K entries into M(-ish) buckets, using the averages for each bucket for your approximation.

Comment: @ScottHunter would you mind elaborating?

Comment: The best I can imagine is fill the M memory slots at random (so not every entry). Thus you can have the last entry, an entry 6 ago, 21 ago, etc.

Comment: Calculate the average of the first M entries: A. Read entry M+1. The new average is `((M * A) + value(M+1)) / (M+1)`. This could well run faster if you batch up the new entries into convenient size groups, adjusting the formula as required.

Comment: @rossum This computes the average value of the entire sequence.

Comment: Start calculating from where the K values start. How variable are the incoming values? If the standard deviation is small, then it may not matter too much.

Comment: K is a sliding window @rossum ,so there is no single point where the K values start (as it is a stream)